# Check battery level in background?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Is it possible to check battery level in swift while our application is in background?

Currently I am working on one iOS application in which user will be alerted with system notification when battery reached to 30%.

I tried and I received notification randomly, sometimes 4%, sometimes 10%, mover than ever 30%.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel <= 0.30 && UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState != UIDeviceBatteryState.Charging)
    {
        Notification.addNotificationSystem("Mettre le portable à charger", fireDate: 1, iconBadgeNumber: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You application is suspended when in the background, so you cannot expect to regularly wake up and check the battery status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code executes the battery test only one time, when the app is going in the background.
If you want to check the battery status while in the background, your app will need to be able to execute actual code there. Which means that you will need to enable one of the `Background Modes` capabilities (**note that Apple will reject your app if you declare to need such an ability without any feature using it**).

**In any case:** If your app gets suspended by iOS, you won't be able to check anything.

[image]

Comment: what mode would you recommend for checking battery status? background fetch?

Comment: Also curious about this, did you ever get it working?

Comment: @quentin Caould you please suggest which one i used for Battery level?